# Convert string array to different types and values using generics in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

**Updated with coding conventions**

I got an array of values:

```
const fruitsArray = ["apple", "banana", "peach"] as const;
```

I use this as base and generated types and values as follows:

```
type FruitsType = (typeof fruitsArray)[number]; // "apple" | "banana" | "peach"
type FruitsTypeMap = { [K in FruitsType]: K }; // {apple: "apple", banana: "banana", peach: "peach"}
const fruitsMap: FruitsTypeMap = fruitsArray.reduce(
    (obj, key) => Object.assign(obj, { [key]: key }),
    {} as FruitsTypeMap
); // {apple: "apple", banana: "banana", peach: "peach"}
```

All are working fine.

My question is how to generate FruitsType, FruitsTypeMap and fruitsMap from fruitsArray using **generics** as I got several other arrays similar to fruitsArray.

Comment: @jcalz: I'm ok with the following: ```function stringArrToMap<K extends string>(arr: readonly K[]) { return Object.fromEntries(arr.map(k => [k, k])) as { [P in K]: P } }``` and calling it with ```const fruitsMap = stringArrToMap(["apple", "banana", "peach"]);```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to abstract your operation to a single [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function `stringArrToMap()` which takes an array of strings and returns an object where each input string becomes an output property where both the key and value are the same.  It could look like this:

```
function stringArrToMap<K extends string>(arr: readonly K[]) {
    return Object.fromEntries(arr.map(k => [k, k])) as { [P in K]: P }
}
```

I changed the implementation to use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) because it's fairly straightforward.  There's no way to do this that the compiler can actually verify as type safe for arbitrary inputs, so I use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that we can treat the returned object as type `{[P in K]: P}`

Let's test it out:

```
const fruitsMap = stringArrToMap(["apple", "banana", "peach"]);
/* const fruitsMap: {
    apple: "apple";
    banana: "banana";
    peach: "peach";
} */
console.log(fruitsMap);
/* {
  "apple": "apple",
  "banana": "banana",
  "peach": "peach"
}  */

const otherMap = stringArrToMap(["a", "b", "c", "x", "y", "z"]);
/* const otherMap: {
    a: "a";
    b: "b";
    c: "c";
    x: "x";
    y: "y";
    z: "z";
} */
console.log(otherMap);
/* {
  "a": "a",
  "b": "b",
  "c": "c",
  "x": "x",
  "y": "y",
  "z": "z"
} */
```

Looks good. The types and values are as expected.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#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)

Comment: thanks. I also need similar thing for `FruitsType` and `FruitsTypeMap` from `fruitsArray` using **generics**.

Comment: My answer already uses **generics**.  Is this a followup question or do you mean that you need that for this current question?  I thought we were in agreement about how this answer should look, so if you need something else maybe there's a communication barrier here.  Maybe [this](https://tsplay.dev/m0v9qw) is what you're looking for... is it?  If so, please give me explicit confirmation so I can edit the answer accordingly.  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: yes your code in typescriptlang.org playground covers other OP parts and it works.  Thanks a lot.